# Incorrect output even with setters in java

Tags: java, class, constructor, output

```
public class Employee {
private String name;
private String jobTitle;
private String department;
private float salary;

public Employee(String name, String jobTitle, String department, float salary){
name = "";
jobTitle = "";
department = "";
salary = 0;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public void setJobTitle(String jobTitle){
    this.jobTitle = jobTitle;
}
public void setDepartment(String department){
    this.department = department;
}
public void setSalary(float salary){
    this.salary = salary;
}
public String getName(){
    return name;
}
 public String getJobTitle(){
    return jobTitle;
}
  public String getDepartment(){
    return department;
}
   public float getSalary(){
    return salary;
}
   public double incrementSalary() {
       return ((salary/100)*2)+ salary;


}
}
```

My test class

```
public class EmployeeTest {
public static void main(String[] args){

Employee employee1 = new Employee("jack","management","ccl",2567);
System.out.println(employee.getSalary());



}

}
```

Hi, new to learning java, I cannot get the correct output, It should outout the salary which is 2567 however I keep getting the default which is 0. I have messed around with it but keep getting null and 0s Any ideas ?

Comment: Huh.  When you call `new Employee()` in your test class, what method does that call?  And what does that method do?

Comment: Fix your constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your constructor does not set any values
it should look like

```
public Employee(String name, String jobTitle, String department,
        float salary) {
    this.name = name;
    this.jobTitle = jobTitle;
    this.department = department;
    this.salary = salary;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your constructor does nothing. You should use `this.name = name`

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
public Employee(String name, String jobTitle, String department, float salary){
    name = "";
    jobTitle = "";
    department = "";
    salary = 0;
}
```

to

```
public Employee(String name, String jobTitle, String department, float salary){
    this.name=name;
    this.jobTitle=jobTitle;
    this.department=department;
    this.salary=salary;
}
```